# Appending string to Prometheus target parameter

Tags: prometheus, spring-actuator

My Prometheus configuration contains the following:

```yaml
- job_name: "spring-actuator-health"
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]
  dns_sd_configs:
    - names:
      - 'tasks.notification-service'
      type: 'A'
      port: 8200
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
```

This might be a very simple question to answer but I somehow can't get my head around it: How can I add a static string `/actuator/health` to `target` parameter which comes from `__address__`?

So the resulting target would look something like `10.4.23.56:8200/actuator/health`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your metric path, you can change:

```
metrics_path: "/probe"
```

to:

```
metrics_path: "/actuator/health"
```

Comment: This will result in the `/actuator/health` being used as a URL path at scrapping, something like `http://my.server.to.monitor/actuator/health?target=my.server.to.monitor`. I'm not sure if that's what OP aimed at.